# How to run eslint with parcel.js in dev mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, eslint, parceljs

I try to migrate from webpack to parcel to reduce the amount of config needed by a basic react (widget) project.
Parcel seems to my fulfill needs, however when I run `parcel index.html --open`, it does not display linter errors.
How can I display eslint warnings in console while compiling ? Can I make it fail or block the compilation ?

(note : I saw the eslint-watcher package, but it scans the dist folder instead of just src and I'm not sure it integrates well with parcel console output).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No_____________